# Download images via AlamofireImage framework with Content-Type: 'binary/octet-stream'

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, alamofire, alamofireimage

I try to download images from Amazon S3 server via AlamofireImage framework.

The Images on the S3 server, save with 'Content-Type' = 'binary/octet-stream'.

In the beginning I got the Error:

```
Failed to validate response due to unacceptable content type.
```

So, I tried to change/update the HTTP Header's request in order to support with binary/octet-stream'

I updated the method:

```
private func URLRequestWithURL(URL: NSURL) -> NSURLRequest
```

In the UIImageView+AlamofireImage.swift file to:

```
private func URLRequestWithURL(URL: NSURL) -> NSURLRequest {
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    mutableURLRequest.addValue("binary/octet-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    return mutableURLRequest
}
```

And is still not working, Just after I added the:

```
let contentTypes: Set<String> = ["Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream"]
Request.addAcceptableImageContentTypes(contentTypes)
```

The problem was solved, But I really don't like the fact that I changed a private method in the AlamofireImage framework.

I wonder if there is an elegant way to solve this problem, given I can't change the images 'Content-Type' in the S3 server.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Doing Request.addAcceptableImageContentTypes(["binary/octet-stream"]) should be all that you need to get it to work.

If you were using af_setImageWithURL, there was a bug that it wasn't using the acceptableImageContentTypes. AlamofireImage 2.2.0 fixes that.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3.2 it's slightly different.

```
       let request = URLRequest(url: URL)
        DataRequest.addAcceptableImageContentTypes(["binary/octet-stream"])
        AlamoDownloader.shared.imageDownloader.download(request){ response in
```

DataRequest is an Alamofire public class.

Comment: @DmitriyGreh Please describe your problem and I'll try to help.